# Why text.size() returns std::size_t and not std::string::size_type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am studying c++ and currently reading C++ Primer (5th ed). I am on the topic about `std::string`. The `size` member returns the length of the string. The book says (p. 88)

```
auto len = line.size(); // len has type string::size_type
```

But Visual Studio Code identifies `len` as having the type `std::size_t`. Why is it different?

Comment: @JeJo Is this compiler-specific? But the fact that the type is std::string::size_type is part of the standard?

Comment: Most compilers use `std::size_t` and that's an 8 byte unsigned integer (typedef for `unsigned long int` on Unix systems and `unsigned long long int` on Windows systems).

Comment: As an implementation detail, they are the same, and Microsoft implementation (being under Microsoft's control) can take advantage of that identity.  Even if it seems confusing (because you'd need to follow the chain of using or typedef to discover that they are indeed the same).  A different implementation they may not be the same, and they would not be able to cavalierly substitute one for the other — it'd cause bugs that would be noticed (hopefully sooner than later).

Comment: The short response is "because the standard says so". All of the standard containers have their own `size_type` by design, allowing different container types to represent size in different ways (e.g. some containers can hold many more elements than others, so need to represent size using a larger integral type). Practically, with most implementations (compilers and libraries) the `size_type` for most containers is `std::size_t`. But the standard allows the option for an implementation to do something different (e.g. make different trade-offs of memory and performance for different containers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> identifies len as having the type `std::size_t`. Why is it different?

From [microsoft's basic_string documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/basic-string-class?view=msvc-170#size_type):

```
typedef typename allocator_type::size_type size_type;
```

> ##### Remarks
>
> it's equivalent to `allocator_type::size_type`.
>
> For type `string`, it's **equivalent to `size_t`**.

(emphasis mine)

Thus, as can be seen from the above quoted remark, for `std::string`, it is equivalent to `size_t`.